# The best way to render list of items from database?

Tags: asp.net, html, database

What would be the best way to render list of many items (like comments that follow articles or blogs) on the web page from a database?

I've noticed in many sites 3 options:

1. Table
2. list of `<ul>` (ul under ul under ul...)
3. list of `<divs>` (div under under div...)

And what asp.net control should i use?
Datalist, repeater?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<ul>` is the best, since it represents a list (and is therefore semantically correct - better for search engine optimization, for accessibility, etc.).

Among your Asp.Net control options, `Repeater` is the best by far, since it gives you complete control over the HTML you render - the other alternatives tend to produce extraneous markup and in some cases inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the [Repeater](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/asp-net-repeater-control/) in cases like this because it is very flexible.  I've used it since 1.1 with all the combinations you've listed, and no problems so far!

I think the semantically correct markup tag choice for a comment list would be `<ol>` (ordered list), assuming your comments will be listed in ascending date order.

Comment: but what tags better to use? table? ul? divs?
i can use any with repeater, but don't know what is better...

Comment: +1, `<ol>` is definitely the way to go when the content is ordered. (But beginners should be aware that these are numbered by default - if you don't want them numbered, be sure to set the list-style to whatever you prefer!)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `<ul>` tag because it is meant for lists. It is better for SEO purposes and you can create a hierchy such as a nested category.

I would not use the repeater or datalist. I would suggest using a MVC **for loop**. It is much faster then the repeater, grid and the datalist.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of your data.

[GridView](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx) - good for tabular data; few or no images required.

[ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790%28loband%29.aspx) - great for product-catalog type data. Great for images and linkage. Check out a [great Listview tutorial by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, "it depends". Basically you should consider how your other site content is presented and stick with that (except if it sucks). However, the `<ul>` element is probably the most correct element to use for a list of items.

For asp.net controls I would recommend that you look at either the [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)  (as other have suggested), or if you want a more feature rich control, that still gives you total control over markup, the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) control.